# Redirect to a dedicated error page?

Tags: php, error-handling

Is there any way in PHP to redirect the browser to a new page upon error whilst maintaining error logging?

1. User performs an action that results in a PHP fatal error
2. The error is logged
3. Browser is redirected to `example.com/error`
4. User is presented with a form, prefilled with the error, and is able to give more details

Comment: Yes.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
or 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp

Comment: Don't **redirect** to error pages. It stops people seeing the URL that caused the error (and therefore using it in bug reports or just fixing a typo themselves).

Comment: Well on a fatal error or something that is clearly a code bug I think it makes more sense. Plus, I can grab the URL and put it in the log.

Comment: It isn't clearly a code bug. It could be created by poor user input. Present the error page at the URL requested, don't redirect to it.

Comment: Quentin: that is not really answering anything, the point is the end-user sees a friendly page saying that the website is currently experiencing technical difficulties. In any case, how do we do this? developdaly have you figured this out?